# Know if express app is running as firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have an express app that I want to run locally as a standalone server in my machine however, when deploying it to firebase cloud functions I need to set it as a cloud function.

Is there a reliable way to know in which environment the app is running without manually setting env variables or what is the best practice?

eg:

```
if(isRunningInFirebase()){
  exports.myFun=functions.https.onRequest(app)
} else app.listen(3030)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are environment variables that are automatically populated in the functions runtime and in locally emulated functions, as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables). One of them for example is the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` variable, which is set to your Firebase project ID. You can have your app checking for it like this:

```
if(process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT) { 
    // running in Firebase environment 
}
else { 
    // running somewhere else 
}
```

Comment: The [documentation for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#reserved_keys_key_validation) proper (not including Firebase additions) suggests that GCLOUD_PROJECT is legacy and GCP_PROJECT is the more correct way to get the project id.

Answer (score 8):

Firebase now sets the `FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR` environment variable when running the emulator:

```
if (process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === 'true') {
    functions are on localhost
} else {
    functions are on Firebase
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did some exploring by logging the process.env

When running functions locally using firebase functions:shell or firebase serve --only functions there are a bunch of local machine type node variables.

When running the deployed function sitting in Firebase Cloud Functions. There is a new node environment variable that is not set when running locally:

```
NODE_ENV: 'production'
```

So to use it:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { 
    // running in production cloud environment 
} else { 
    // running locally (shell or serve) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not having to edit a program before running it locally or on googles  computers remotely saves a lot of time.

The object process.env is asserted both locally and when run in the cloud. It differs hugely, but here's a property I think is reliable,  easy to understand, and to use.

This stand alone code says where it is, and sets the variable port to a usual number I use for both circumstances.

```
// Dan K The program wants to know, where am I ?
'use strict'

console.log( "program ID: " + "zincoNoDogs13" );

// Make a message and set a port number for other uses depending on whether the
// program wakes up on a local computer or in google cloud

const functions = require( 'firebase-functions' );
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest( app );

var port;
var imaThis = "local";
let lookie = process.env.HOME;
if( lookie == "/tmp" ) { imaThis = "cloud"; }

if( imaThis == "local" ) {console.log( "I am on a local computer" ); port = 3000; }
if( imaThis == "cloud" ) {console.log( "I am in the clouds man" ); port = 80; }

console.log( "Port number is going to be: " + port );
```

**You get one or the other, or well, I do anyway:**

program ID: zincoNoDogs13
I am in the clouds man
Port number is going to be: 80

program ID: zincoNoDogs13
I am on a local computer
Port number is going to be: 3000